# SATA Drives On Intel 945 Board

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, sata

I have an old/dead (assembled) Intel 945G Pentium 4 3.0 Ghz machine. I bought new seagate SATA HDD & SATA DVD Drive & connected to it.

I have been facing below error while booting up:

1. Booting process stops at 5A / Press F2 to enter setup screen.
2. Sometimes when booting proceeds I get message `No bootable drive found` (With windows 7 disk in DVD drive & DVD drive set as first boot device)

I see intel community doing different hit & try methods viz. update BIOS, reset CMOS etc. I could not find a well concluded solution.

Any one, could you make SATA drives work properly on Intel 945 board?

Comment: What is your computer model, and which Intel 945 Board you have (P, G, GM etc.) ?

Comment: It is an assembled PC, Intel 945G I think.

Comment: Let us know which drive you bought, as the 945G only supports up to SATA II. You should also upgrade your drivers from the [Intel Download Center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng).

Comment: @harrymc DVD drive is: `HP DVD1260i-UH06C` & Hard drive is `Seagate ST500DM002`

Comment: Which *exact* motherboard do you have ? Or if it's a PreBuilt PC - e.g. Dell or HP, which *exact* model do you have ?

Comment: Also, can it boot off USB ? Maybe it's worth booting up a Linux Live distro off USB and see if it can pick up the SATA controller / SATA drives

Comment: @Lawrence I will try with Live Distro..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Seagate ST500DM002](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/desktop-hdd/#specs) hard disk is SATA III, while the [Intel 945G specs](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/mainboard/i945-i955-chipsets-specs.html)
only mention SATA II.

It seems that your hard disk is too recent for that board.
A SATA III disk is said to work on a SATA II adapter at SATA II speeds,
but maybe this doesn't work with your board, or that Windows is using
the wrong driver. You should
at least try to upgrade your drivers from the [Intel Download Center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng).

For more details see [wikipedia Serial ATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA).

If your old board cannot handle this disk, you could maybe find some older and slower disk that the board will support. In any case, putting a fast disk on such an old board with such a slow bus is a bit of a waste.

If you really insist on using this disk, and if the latest Intel disk-drivers work for you, you will need to [slipstream](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-build-a-slipstream-windows-7-install-disc-7151) the Intel drivers into your own Windows 7 boot USB, or [install a boot-start driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For the BIOS you may be able to find an update bootable CD, or [make your own](http://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-boot-cd.htm).

Comment: Can't update the BiOS until the system is running. As it is new HDD & DVD drive is not detected, I have limited options.

Comment: @Abhijeet - You don't need a working operating system to update the BIOS.